Reading parquet files in C++
I have a parquet file that I have been able to parse in python and extract the needed data as follows:
import pandas as pd
import shapely.wkb
import shapely.geometry
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import utm

df = pd.read_parquet("lanes_small.parquet", engine="fastparquet")

plt.figure()
for index, object in df.iterrows():
    if not "segment" in object["id"]:
        continue
    linestring = shapely.wkb.loads(object["geometry"])
    coordinates = shapely.geometry.mapping(linestring)["coordinates"]
    xy_coordinates = [utm.from_latlon(lat, lon) for lon, lat in coordinates]
    plt.plot(
        [xy_coord[1] for xy_coord in xy_coordinates],
        [xy_coord[0] for xy_coord in xy_coordinates],
    )

plt.show()

But I am unable to do the same in C++, the closest I have gotten is this:
arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input;
input = *arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(path);

std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> arrow_reader;
arrow::Status open_status = parquet::arrow::OpenFile(input, pool, &arrow_reader);
if(!open_status.ok()){
    std::cout << "Failed open: " << open_status.ToString();
}

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table;
arrow::Status read_table_status = arrow_reader->ReadTable(&table);
if(!read_table_status.ok()){
    std::cout << "Failed read: " << read_table_status.ToString() << std::endl;
}

Which ends with Failed read: NotImplemented: Support for codec 'snappy' not built
And I have added snap to the conan project:
[requires]
snappy/1.2.0
arrow/15.0.0

[options]
arrow/*:parquet=True
arrow/*:with_boost=True
arrow/*:with_thrift=True
arrow/*:snappy=True

Any input of what I should do?

The "of little help" documentation for Tables tells me there's a GetColumnByName method that returns a column that you can index by row number (of which there are num_rows(). So create a loop from 0 to num_rows and use that to index into the columns you are interested in. Python is hiding the column-oriented nature of Parquet from you and pretending you have a row-based datastructure, while the C++ API does not have any such pretense.

"I have tried about 100 different ways but none of them work" is not useful information, apart from that it conveys that you are frustrated, because it doesn't actually tell us what else you tried.  But people will help you even if you're not frustrated. If you want to show additional relevant things you've tried then show them. Otherwise, you can probably delete that sentence, and trust that people will help you even if you've only tried 99 other ways.  ;)  (The fact that you've tried many things before asking should be true of every question on SO, so it's not necessary to say explicitly.)

@Botje I am unable to use the variable since the read failed, or am I missing something.

That's the danger of asking several questions at once. Did you reinstall/recompile the arrow library after setting that flag? Did you make sure the snappy support was built? Did you make sure to link against the arrow-with-snappy library? We need more information to a) reproduce the problem and b) formulate a solution.

FWIW I took your conanfile.txt, modified the parquet-reader-writer example Modified it to use snappy compression and everything Just Works(tm). So if something is wrong it is with the way you compiled your program. But you will have to edit your question to show us...

@JakobVinkas you might check out an older example of building an Arrow program with CMake+Conan, see https://github.com/amoeba/arrow-cpp-conan-example.

Your conanfile.txt and the rest of the setup looks correct.
The issues you encountered were most likely caused by nearly all of the options (including arrow/*:snappy=True) in the arrow package being broken due to a bug in the recipe on ConanCenter. This was fixed only quite recently on 2024-04-09 by the following PR: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/23163.
You should run conan remove arrow -c to purge any existing cached versions of arrow.
